# What is the proper data structure for search the same value by multiple keys(string)?

Tags: c, data-structures

For example, if it's 1 key to 1 value, I will use a hash table

```
key  value
aaa  AAA
bbb  AAb
ccc  AAc
```

My situation is the input key has multiple fields like this:

```
key                                       value
name: aaa, class: bbb, prop: ccc          AAA
name: aaa, class: bbc, prop: ccd          AAB
name: aab, class: bbb, prop: ccc          AAC
name: aac, class: bbc, prop: ccc          AAD
```

So I will do `find value from DS where name=` or `where class=` or `where prop=`.

I can only come up with creating 3 hash tables, is there any proper data struct to use?

Comment: You might consider [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) with some in-memory database. Or several consistent hash-tables or dictionnaries.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you want to index the same value by 3 different keys.
I'd say 3 hash tables is a fair choice in this case.

You might want to bundle them together in a struct (or class if you are using C++) so they can be passed around together and stay consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a struct key containing all 3 keys and then your search algorithm will look for matching members of the struct. You could then proceed using a regular hash table.

Dictionaries are also an option. However, you have the reverse situation of what a dictionary is designed for (one key -> multiple values) so you'd have to modify the dictionary to work in 'reverse'.